# Multi-field queries using C# driver for MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm having trouble figuring out syntax for what I'm trying to accomplish. As stated I'm using the C# driver for MongoDB.

I have a User entity defined as

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class User : MongoEntity
{
    [BsonElement]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a UserService class that performs actions against the User collection in my mongo database. Below is an example of how i'm creating a real simple login example.

```
public UserPresentation Login(string username, string password)
{
    var entityQuery = Query<User>.EQ(e => e.Username, username.ToUpper());

    var entity = this.MongoConnectionHandler.MongoCollection.FindOne(entityQuery);

    return (entity != null && entity.Id.ToString().Length > 0 && entity.Password == password) ? new UserPresentation(entity) : null;
}
```

This works, however my question is... instead of creating a Query that only looks for Username == username, returning the element and then comparing the password in an if statement, can I somehow append more fields to the intial `entityQuery` object.

Comment: `Query.And`? Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Query.And()` like this...

```
var entityQuery = Query.And(
                      Query<User>.EQ(e => e.Username, username.ToUpper()),
                      Query<User>.EQ(e => e.Password, password)
                  );
```

See [CSharp Driver Tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#CSharpDriverTutorial-FindOneandFindOneAsmethods)

Or you could do it LINQ style, see: [CSharp Driver LINQ Tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/)

This is also interesting too: [How to rewrite a MongoDB C# LINQ with a Projection Requirement using a MongoCursor](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1835)

Comment: Nice I think the more LINQ approach is really what I was after from the beginning. I feel kind of dumb for not remembering how to do this, but perhaps this will save someone else a few minutes of poking around.

Comment: Don't feel dumb! :) As the popularity of MongoDB continues to grow, I'm sure it will help, so +1 for the question ;)